# Count status code in log file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to count the amount of times a status code repeats in a log file. This is an example of the content of the file `'10.10.10.10 - - [29/Aug/2017:06:29:44 -0400] "GET /isomaster/download/ HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "curl/7.49.1"\n'` but it repeats multiple hundred times with different requests containing different status codes. This is my attempt to getting the count of all 200 status code.

```
def loadFiles():

    #READ From access_log
    access_0 = open('file0','r')
    line_0 = access_0.readlines() #readlines() read the text line per line 
    print(line_0)
    access_0.close()


    access_1 = open('file1','r')
    line_1 = access_1.readlines() #readlines() read the text line per line 
    return print(line_1)
    access_1.close()

    access_2 = open('file2','r')
    line_2 = access_2.readlines() #readlines() read the text line per line 
    return print(line_2)
    access_2.close()

    access_3 = open('file3','r')
    line_3 = access_3.readlines()
    return print(line_3)
    access_3.close()    

def total_200():

        values = loadFiles()
        values_200 = re.findall(r'\d{200}\s',values) 
        string_count = values_200.count('200')
        print(string_count)
```

The `loadFiels()` loads in the content of all the multiple files I want to read, but what this does is only print the all the strings with the status code 200, it doesn't not count it. Any suggestions on how to go about this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`string_count` is a list. You can simply use `len(string_count)` to get the integer count.

Comment: I'm getting an error at  `values_200 = re.findall(r'\d{200}\s',values)` because it's expecting a string or a byte-like object where `values` is since my file is in a list format. Would I need to convert this list into a string or is there a better way of getting around this?

Comment: @Katz maybe you can just loop through the list. So run this for each value in 'values'.